# Django HoneyPot Change Password Issue

Tags: python, django, passwords, honeypot

I would appreciate if you could give me any clue! As I don't have experience in this, probably I've misunderstood smth.

I'm using *honeypot*, more specifically `honeypot.middleware.HoneypotMiddleware` with `HONEYPOT_FIELD_NAME` in my API (*settings.py*).

As for the moment it's enough, I'm using the basic implementation for *login, password change, reset* from `django.contrib.auth`. In *login* I did a small customization so I added it in the url (`authentication_form=CustomAuthenticationForm`).

So I don't konw what I'm missing because the *login* page works (it is also a form), but the *password change, reset* ones are returning *400 Bad Request. Honey Pot Error (honey_pot_fieldname). Request aborted*.

django: 2.1.2
django-honeypot: 0.7.0

**[Updating with code]**

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
....
    'honeypot',
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'honeypot.middleware.HoneypotMiddleware',
]

HONEYPOT_FIELD_NAME = config('HONEYPOT_FIELD_NAME')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
        'suspended': _("Your account has been temporarily suspended. For more information,\
                   please contact us."),
    }

    def clean(self)
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view

urlpatterns = [
....

    # ---- BASIC USER AUTHENTICATION (DJANGO)
    path('api/login/', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=CustomAuthenticationForm), name='login'),
    path('api/logout/', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    # ---- PASSWORD CHANGE, RESET
    path('api/password_change/', auth_view.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('api/password_change_done/', auth_view.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(),
         name='password_change_done'),
....
]
```

**[Templates]**

*templates/resgistration/login.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}

{% block head %}
    {% load bootstrap3 %}

    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center" >User login</h1>
        <legend></legend>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
            {% buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" style="margin-top: 20px">Log in</button>
            {% endbuttons %}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

*templates/resgistration/password_change_form.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}
{% block head %}
    {% load bootstrap3 %}

    {{ form.media }} 
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center" >{{ title }}</h1>
        <legend></legend>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
            {% buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" style="margin-top: 20px">Change password</button>
            {% endbuttons %}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair. Code added.

Comment: There it goes @Alasdair! If I comment the HoneyPot then it works, so I suppose that I missing smth with HoneyPot and Django built-in login system. Thanks!

Comment: I can't spot the problem I'm afraid. Hopefully somebody else will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Alasdair! Probably I'm wrong but I suspect that HoneyPot covers the app layer, but not the built-in solutions...

Answer (score 1):

**[Updating with solution]**

Finally I achieved it!
I only had to add at the top of the template *change_password_form.html* the line

```
{% load honeypot %}
```

and within the form including the tag:

```
{% render_honeypot_field "field_name" %}
```

For achieve this helped me this article
[django-honeypot](http://www.filehungry.com/product/linux_software/utilities/django-honeypot/)

Hope that will be helpful for others.